# How to save data transposed in a tab-delimited file

Tags: matlab

Assuming you have an array of 5 lines by `n` columns as a MATLAB variable.
How do you save to a file each column of the array into a new array as as follows:

column1 becomes line1 and so on.

I need this to be without comas between elements so it should be something along the lines of

```
dlmwrite('pointcloud.pts', cloud, 'delimiter', '\t');
```

[image]

produces

[image]

but I want column one to be saved as line one.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current use of `dlmwrite`? Maybe you just need to transpose `cloud`?

Comment: Your actual data is usually not helpful in asking a question here because we don't have access to it and can't use it to run code. A picture adds little in this case. You should instead create an example matrix, as @13aumi has helpfully done, to illustrate what is happening and what your desired behavior is. [For future reference](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only have to transpose your matrix. Here's an example:

```
n = 7;
test = rand(5, n);
dlmwrite('pointcloud.pts', test', 'delimiter', '\t');
```

For me it works fine. -> ' <- is the operator to transpose... Or did I understand you wrong?

EDIT: Look, I think that you are still saving the not transposed matrix. So in your case you are still saving the first 443250 elements of the first row into the first row of your file. By transposing your data with the apostroph ' you transpose the data and can store it correctly. Have a look at my code: you will see one apostrophe (as operator to transpose) after >test<.

You can see that for example if you type:

```
a = rand(2, 4);
a_transposed = a';
```